# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when closing Hibernate Session in Java Swing application

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate, orm

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.close()Ljava/sql/Connection;
```

When calling this function:

```
private static SessionFactory factory;

public static void insert(Object model) {

    factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {

        session.save(model);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (HibernateException exc) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        exc.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close(); // here is when the error occurs
    }
}
```

I believe I have imported all the necessary jars from `/lib/required/` directory in the latest Hibernate 5.0.1.

The `hibernate.cfx.xml` file is also correctly configured:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property >

        <mapping  resource="customer.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And `customer.hbm.xml` mapping file:

```
<class name="com.test.app.model.Customer" table="customer">

    <meta attribute="class-description">
        Test.
    </meta>

    <id column="id" name="id" type="int">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="name"           column="name"               type="string"/>
    <property name="phoneNumbers"   column="phone_numbers"      type="string"/>
    <property name="emailAddresses" column="email_addresses"    type="string"/>
    <property name="address"        column="address"            type="string"/>
    <property name="note"           column="note"               type="string"/>
</class>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: what are the other libraries your project may have?

Comment: well I also have Absolute Layout and MySQL JDBC Driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have two `hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar` in your classpath. For example, if you run a project in the IDE and add other project with `hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar` to your classpath.

P.S. Please don't configure the session factory in every insert, and rollback on any exception, not only on `HibernateException`. You can see how properly working with transactions [here](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/cfg/HibernateSessionFactory.java), and you can find a simply example console project using Hibernate 5 and MySQL [here](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/tree/master/fluent-hibernate-examples/simply-console/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql).

Comment: @user2200690 Thank you. Fixed.