# Hiberanate 5.2.0.Final java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.close()V

Tags: hibernate, session, nosuchmethoderror

I'm getting an error while trying to close hibernate session using the version 5.2.0, I'm starting to get the issue since I migrated to Hibernate 5.2.0 Final version, I searched over internet but I still don't find a solution :(

my code is very simple :

I create the session later on after doing the transaction I try to close it as following :

final Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
       try{

[my transaction ...]

```
        }
        finally{
                session.close();
        }
```

It seems that it doesn't recognize the close() method which is generating the below Error :

PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) [com.utils.ServletContextClass]
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.close()V**

Could you help me please? is there a known issue with closing hibernate session related to the hibernate 5.2.0 Final version?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem now... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had a Java library compiled against Hibernate 4.3. Changing the classpath to use Hibernate 5.4 resulted in a similar `NoSuchMethodError` on `session.close()`.

I was able to resolve my problem by recompiling the Java library against Hibernate 5.4.

This may be a similar question, which was solved by removing redundant Hibernate Jars from the classpath:
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when closing Hibernate Session in Java Swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32817518/1695742)